# JS: why don't alert message when i click button?

Tags: javascript, onclick, addeventlistener

I try the code below but when i click button does not show the alert message!

```
let clickButton = document.getElementsByClassName("buttonClass");

clickButton.onclick = clickFunc;

function clickFunc(){ alert("hello")};

console.log(clickButton);
```

[i create buttons with document.createElement](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4OXaQ.png)

[console log return this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xvZG3.png)

I have try:

1. To choose only one button like this `let clickButton = document.getElementsByClassName("buttonClass")[1];` but nothing
2. Also i have try to get element by tagname, loop with a length of buttons, and addeventlistener, but nothing again

Comment: `getElementsByClassName` return an **array**, not a single button

Answer (score 0):

```js
let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("buttonClass");
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons.item(i).addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    alert("hello");
  });
}
```

```html
<button type="button" class="buttonClass">button 1</button>
<button type="button" class="buttonClass">button 2</button>
<button type="button" class="buttonClass">button 3</button>
<button type="button" class="buttonClass">button 4</button>
<button type="button" class="buttonClass">button 5</button>
```

Since your targeting by class, you get an array of elements. So you have to iterate and attach click events to each element as show below;

```
let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("buttonClass");
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons.item(i).addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    alert("hello");
  });
}
```

Comment: First thank you for your help! I try the code above but nothing. I make a console log(buttons); and nothing change!

Comment: Did you add the buttons with the class? Anyways, I've added a working snippet. Please check that.